# How to deploy both master and branch?

Tags: git, github

I have a project as A in gitHub. A is deployed in server by using deploy keys. My customer asked for currection work, I have created branch for A and coded.

Now how to  deploy bothe master and branch? or else is there any other solution to deploy branch for correction work approval.

Comment: Do you have test, integration,dev environments?

Comment: just send him the branch code and tell him to open it locally on a browser bro. No need to deploy. if you want to deploy both , then make separate repo for both branches and deploy them both on github pages or merge those two branches and deploy it as one.

Answer (score 0):

Best practice is creating a tag for the commit , so that you can deploy the tag created and its easy to maintain the stable version of the code using
git tagging
There are two types of tags:

Annotated

```
git tag -a v1.2 -m "my version 1.4"
```

Lightweight

```
git tag v1.
```